# Div with constant height variable width

Tags: html, css

There is a Div of width say 500px and height 50px.
Inside this Div there are many (say 50) small Div of width 50px and height 50 px.
Now i want a horizontal scroll instead of a vertical one.
How can i force those small divs to overflow horizontally not vertically

Also number of small divs can change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the following CSS to the outer `DIV`:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

See an example at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXe9b/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the child div's to `display: inline-block`, then set the parent to `white-space: nowrap`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Inline-block has its limits. Should not be used on elements that are block. Float:left will work just fine.

Comment: Very true about inline-block, but it does work fine on everything higher than ie6, which I haven't supported for a while now so I tend not to worry about it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

the main div style define

```
 float : left; 
 overflow : scroll;
```